# HTML Drop down list selected="selected" or "yes" is not working in Firefox and chrome

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I'm reloading page after changing drop down list. Attribute selected="selected" is adding to choose option.But Drop down is not showing selected option, it is always showing first option in Firefox and Chrome. It is working in IE.

Comment: um, yeah, you reloaded the page. Only browser caching is going to keep the selection around.

Comment: I think it is not reloading issue. Selected attribute is not working in Firefox and Chrome. How it is working in IE browsers? Please don't select -1 :(.

Comment: you mean *nothing* is selected in FF or Chrome? If so, you need to make a fiddle for this, or show SOME code. What you have here is not enough to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `<option selected>` instead of `<option selected="selected">`